# "500 Failed to retrieve records" error using PostgreSQL service with DreamFactory

Tags: postgresql, dreamfactory

I've configured the service, app, and roles for my endpoint. I can successfully run API calls from the DreamFactory  API Docs on /schema, /function, /table - basically all the single nodes that don't have a table name.

When I do add a table name  (e.g., /table/myTableName) I receive a 500 error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "context": null,
    "message": "Failed to retrieve records from 'getresidents'.\nSQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column d.adsrc does not exist\nLINE 1: ...ER(format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod)) AS type, d.adsrc, a...\n                                                             ^ (SQL: SELECT a.attname, LOWER(format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod)) AS type, d.adsrc, a.attnotnull, a.atthasdef,\n\tpg_catalog.col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment\nFROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum\nWHERE a.attnum &gt; 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped\n\tAND a.attrelid = (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_class WHERE relname=:table\n\t\tAND relnamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE nspname = :schema))\nORDER BY a.attnum)",
    "status_code": 500
  }
}
```

This even occurs when running from the API Docs inside of the DreamFactory app.

I am running this as an admin user and still getting this error.

Are there any specific permissions I need to have on the user? I'm even trying with the default postgres user and am getting this error.

I could really use help from anyone who can offer assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this.
I was running PostgreSQL 13. So I decided to create a PostgreSQL version 12 install. The connection worked. Not sure why, but it looks like things work without a hitch in 12 but not with 13. Would be interesting to hear from the developers any input on this.

Answer (score 0):

We've looked into this issue and indeed PostgreSQL 13 is not supported in the current DreamFactory version due to a simple coding oversight pertaining to version number detection. We've identified the issue and will be releasing a new version of DreamFactory later this week with the fix in place!

Thank you,
Jason